# как пройтись по ключам словаря когда они списки

Tags: python, словари, dict

```
countries = {
    "Sweden": ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö"],
    "Norway": ["Oslo", "Bergen", "Trondheim"],
    "England": ["London", "Birmingham", "Manchester"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"],
    "France": ["Paris", "Marseille", "Toulouse"]
}
count = 0
city = input()
for i in countries:
    if city == i:
        print(i)
    else:
        count +=1
    if count == 4:
        print(f"ERROR: Country for {city} not found")
```

Есть такой вот код, мне нужно пройтись по каждому ключу и проверить наличие там указанного города

Если сделать так:

```
for i in countries("Sweden"):
```

То искать будет в пределах ключа Sweden, как мне пройтись по каждому из елементов?

Метод решения только через словарь

Comment: а где это у вас ключи словаря - списки?

Answer (score 3):

вы можете воспользоваться методом **items()** для словарей. Например:

```
countries = {
    "Sweden": ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö"],
    "Norway": ["Oslo", "Bergen", "Trondheim"],
    "England": ["London", "Birmingham", "Manchester"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"],
    "France": ["Paris", "Marseille", "Toulouse"]
}

def search(city):
    for key, value in countries.items():
        if city in value:
            return f"City in {key}"
    return f"ERROR: Country for {city} not found"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    city = input()
    print(search(city))
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, можно сразу составить *обратный словарь* `город -> страна` и брать информацию из него:

```py
countries = {
    "Sweden": ["Stockholm", "Göteborg", "Malmö"],
    "Norway": ["Oslo", "Bergen", "Trondheim"],
    "England": ["London", "Birmingham", "Manchester"],
    "Germany": ["Berlin", "Hamburg", "Munich"],
    "France": ["Paris", "Marseille", "Toulouse"]
}

cities = {city:country for country,cities in countries.items() for city in cities}
city = input()
country = cities.get(city)
print(f'{city} is in {country}' if country else f'ERROR: Country for {city} not found')
```